# qr-code scanner in Angular2

Tags: angular, webpack, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I am trying to implement an Angular 2 web-application with barcode scan functionality.

I haven't yet found a library I get to work with Angular2 + webpack.

Does anyone have an idea for libraries and/or tutorials how to get an external library for this functionality to work?

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: did you find something , to scan QR code using angular2 
@comeback4you

Comment: If you two didn' find anything yet: I just used a javascript library for that. I didn't find any useful Angular 2 implementation.